# which is more intuitive time picker?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, time

I need to know which is more user-freindly.

**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2**
[image]

One gif shows changes in minutes affecting hour and in another gif, that does not happen. Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: Your 1st option seems to be able to be changable only in 15 min interval. Unless thats intentional, you will have trouble selecting times that aren't in the range: e.g. 4:54pm

Comment: It's hard to determine which is easier and more efficient out of context. Option 1 suggests that I can type my own numbers because the numbers look like they're in textboxes.

Comment: I think the question is limited to the difference where in case 1 changing the minutes influences the hour. All other differences in these mockups need need to be ingnored I think.

Comment: changing the hour in option 1 should reset the minutes to zero-zero. if only more people liked me, i'd buy a sports car to make them happy

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my opinion, Option 2 is the most user friendly.

Reasoning:
If the hour has its own up and down arrow you do not expect that using the up and down arrow of the minutes can change the hour as well. to me, individual controls means individual effect.

If you want to have the effect of changing the minutes influencing the hours, this is what you need:

[image] or [image]

You may want to add accelerator behaviour to this approach because otherwise, changing the time with a large offset will be frustrating. I am not in favor using this approach though. I would go for your solution nr 2.

Comment: @Jivan: You should not accept answers this fast. This will reduce the incentive for other users to come with competing answers, possibly leading to a better result than what I have posted.

Answer (score 7):

**Use separate textboxes for the `hour` and `minute` values and a pair of radio buttons for `AM/PM` value.**

*Typing* desired values is usually easier (quicker) than clicking or pressing a button to get to them. Just think about the worst-case scenarios for the number ranges you're using.

For a 12-hour clock, the greatest distance is 6 if you can go directly from `12` to `1` and vice versa; for minutes in an hour, the greatest distance is 30 if you can go directly from `59` to `00` and vice versa.

So, let's assume the default is `12`:`00` and I want to input `6`:`30`. I have to press the Increase Hours button 6 times and the Increase Minutes button 30 times. That's a max total of 36 mouse clicks not including possible clicks for AM/PM selection and form submission.

I could hold down these buttons for indeterminate amounts of seconds, but that's part of the problem: it's hard to predict ahead of time how much to hold.

In contrast, if I'm able to type and I want `6`:`30`, I just go:

<kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Hunynh  I totally agree with you. In my project, Desired value (missing attendance record) is most likely to be near to default time(shift time). Thats why i preferred this design.

Answer (score 4):

If the time is in a single field, e.g. [10.00], then clicking the up/down arrow would increment it by 5 or 15 minute intervals (Google Calendar does this).

If the hours are in one field and the minutes are in another e.g. [10] : [00], then their respective up/down buttons should only increment their values, not the whole time (the time selector on one of the iPhone apps does this, can't remember which one).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the other good answers, I would like to point out that Android used to follow Option 1 (at least as late as Android 4.0), but switched at some point to Option 2. The behavior must have been changed on purpose, quite possibly due to actual usability testing.

Based on that, this is more evidence that Option 2 is indeed the more usable choice.

Comment: Android now has a clock-face time picker. I'm surprised no one mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any testing on this, but I do notice my own frustrations when using these things.

Let's say I need 10:45. In option 1, I'd pick 10 in the hours and realize it's shorter to go backward from 00 to 45 than to go forward. So I'd go backward from 00 and the widget would flip  my 10 to a 9. So I'd have to re-pick the hours. No thank you.

Of your two options, I'd go with #2.